# Arquivo SVG kartograph

Tags: javascript, svg

Utilizando o kartograph, eu quero carregar o SVG desse link: [SVG](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cf/SantaCatarina_MesoMicroMunicip.svg).  A primeira coisa que notei que estava faltando era a tag metadata. Então eu copiei essa tag de um outro arquivo SVG, porém a imagem continua nao aparecendo.
Alguém poderia olhar o arquivo svg do link e me dizer o que está faltando?

Abaixo o meu código html.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="../../js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../js/raphaeljs/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../js/kartograph/kartograph.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){

                    var map = kartograph.map('#map');
                    map.loadMap('mymap.svg', function () {
                            map.addLayer("Terreno");
                    });
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu não testei ainda está biblioteca, mas suponho que por ser raphael.js você esteja trabalhando com canvas combinado ao svg estou certo?

Comment: Não sei dizer, aqui na página inicial do kartograph[http://kartograph.org/] tem uns exemplos

Comment: Se a minha reposta não lhe ajudar, **edite** a sua questão a adicione um exemplo funcional do problema usando o snippet (do próprio stackoverflow) ou http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solução foi gerar o mapa usando o Kartograph py a partir de arquivos SHP.

Answer (score 0):

Não consigo reproduzir o problema, então vou apontar os possíveis erros no código:

1. No seu código você está a usar as versão 1.9.1 do Jquery `<script src="../../js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

   Mas o kartograph usa a versão 1.10.2 `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`
2. No seu código você *pode* estar usando uma versão desatualizada do raphael, o kartograph usa "raphael 2.1.0" (como eu disse "pode", não tem como ter certeza)
3. SVG está em um domínio diferente do atual, o seu SVG pode estar em um domínio diferente da página que está usando o "kartograph", isto pode ocasionar problemas com o ["CORS"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

### Outros possíveis problemas

Os arquivos não estão no diretório correto, para determinar a falha analise o Console do seu navegador, veja como fazer aqui: http://ggnome.com/wiki/Using_The_Browser_Error_Console
   Se o Console mostrar algum erro, através deste "erro", você vai saber qual o problema do seu código.

Comment: 1 Não é a versao do Jquery porque funciona usando um svg dos exemplos do site. 2 A versao do raphael que estou usando é a última disponível no site. 3 o arquivo svg está localmente no servidor eu coloquei a url da fonte pra poderem acessar o arquivo. Vou fazer o jsfiddle pra reproduzir

Comment: @luckasx Amigo é como eu disse "vou apontar os possíveis", siga a indicação da onde está escrito **"Outros possíveis problemas"**, a sua pergunta não tem como reproduzir o problema, como eu disse no meu primeiro comentário (aonde eu falo "snippet (do próprio stackoverflow) ou jsfiddle.net")